# How can I know if I've already played a segment of an M3U8 video?

Tags: live-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm writing an m3u8 player and have a small issue. One m3u8 video I'm trying to play returns a media sequence that has nothing to do with the segment file names and the file names repeat themselves forever. How can I know if I already played a given segment?

This is what the requests look like over a few seconds:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:5609
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10.000000,
channel001.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
channel000.ts
```

Then a few seconds later:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:5610
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10.000000,
channel000.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
channel001.ts
```

Then again a few seconds later:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:5611
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10.000000,
channel001.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
channel000.ts
```

so the segment names are the same, the media sequence doesn't tell me much. How can I know if I already played those specific segments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segment names don't matter, you always use the media sequence. `MEDIA-SEQUENCE` is incremented each time a segment is removed from the playlist.

> **3.  Media Segments**

> ...

> Each segment in a Media Playlist has a unique integer Media Sequence
> Number.  The Media Sequence Number of the first segment in the Media
> Playlist is either 0 or declared in the Playlist (Section 4.3.3.2).
> The Media Sequence Number of every other segment is equal to the
> Media Sequence Number of the segment that precedes it plus one.

and

> **6.3.5.  Determining the Next Segment to Load**

> ...

> The first segment to load is generally the segment that the client
> has chosen to play first (see Section 6.3.3).

> In order to play the presentation normally, the next Media Segment to
> load is the one with the lowest Media Sequence Number that is greater
> than the Media Sequence Number of the last Media Segment loaded.

[RFC 8216 - HTTP Live Streaming](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216)

Comment: So I read that documentation and I guess I'm just not understanding it. Let's say that I get an m3u8 with 4 ts files, A, B, C, D. The media sequence is zero. I play A, then B, then C, then D, then I refresh the m3u8 and I get C, D, E, F. How do I know that I already played C and D the previous time I loaded the m3u8?

Comment: @casolorz You loaded A(0), B(1), C(2), D(3). You need 4 next. On refresh A, B are removed so `EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE` is now 2. The playlist contains C(2), D(3), E(4), F(5). Since you need 4 you skip the first two.

Comment: I think I understand, basically media sequence changes by one for every segment that is removed?

Comment: Yes, it's mentioned right there in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Is the media sequence number always for the first segment on the file? I guess that was my confusion, I thought the media sequence pointed at some segment within the file.

Comment: Yes, you got it.