# Configuring m3u8 file to run with ts segments that don't change the names

Tags: live-streaming, m3u8

i don't know much about this and how to configure it.
I have 4 segments that don't change the name, they are (segment1.ts, segment2.ts, segment3.ts, segment4.ts) but they are updated every 5 seconds (but keeps same name).
i think the m3u8 it's configured right, only the MEDIA-SEQUENCE that is wrong, and i don't know how should i configure it, any helps??

```
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:28578
#EXTINF:5.000,
segment1.ts
#EXTINF:5.000,
segment2.ts
#EXTINF:5.000,
segment3.ts
#EXTINF:5.000,
segment4.ts
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212005/how-can-i-know-if-ive-already-played-a-segment-of-an-m3u8-video. See this

Comment: You have to control the MEDIASEQ number to increment +1 each time you represent a new segment file in a manifest. If you update 1-4 rolling files you need to maintain a logical representation ordering. Simple example on each manifest update 1,2,3,4 | 3,4,1,2 | 1,2,3,4 ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the playlist each time a new segment is available. The client (player) will reload the playlist periodically to check for new segments.

If you only keep a limited number of segments you will use a fixed-size sliding window: the oldest segment is removed once a new one is refreshed and added. You generally want to maintain the same playlist duration and not the segment count since segments can have different durations.

`EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE` must be incremented by one for each segment **removed** from the playlist, not when adding as mentioned in the comments.

You **cannot reuse** only 4 segments for a 4 segment sliding window. Each time you remove a segment from the playlist it **still needs to be available on the server** for a time equal to the duration of the segment plus the maximum playlist duration published by the server so far.